# Data Persistence in C++ - Suggest better approach

Tags: c++, design-patterns, class-design

We are working on a replicating tool, which replicates different folders from a client machine to a server machine on a periodic basis.

When a particular folder has to be replicated, a replicating object is created(by our service module) on the client side which sends the contents of the files present in the folder over the network to the server. On the server a corresponding receiving object is created(by our service module) which receives the files.

**Nutshell:**

Client Side Abstraction - Replication object (running in its own thread), whose responsibility is to send the files.
Server Side Abstraction - Receiving object (running in its own thread), responsibility is to receive the contents and create/update the files.

Now an additional requirement has come where we need certain counters, like total bytes sent, total bytes received, last replicating time, ... for each folder which is replicated. These counter needs to be persisted as long as our service is running (no requirement of persisting this across our service/machine reboots).

To incorporate these changes there are two approaches we are debating on.

**Please Note** - The counter needs to be maintained across replication cycles.

**Approach1** : Object Reuse

Make counters part of replication, receiving objects and keep the receiving and replication objects alive as long as the service is alive. 
Now for the thread, any of the following approach can be taken.

1. Keep the object as well as thread alive (the thread goes into a sleep). Now during the next replicating cycle the object and thread(awake the thread) is re-used.
2. Allow the thread to exit, persisting the replicating, receiving object. Now during the next replicating cycle; replicating, receiving object re-creates a thread or gets a thread from a thread pool.

**Approach2** : Encapsulation

Encapsulate the counters in a separate class. Now whenever a receiving/replicating object is instantiated for replicating a folder. Either

1. Pass the counter object, corr. to the folder as an argument to Receiving/Replicating object constructor.

OR

1. Receiving/Replicating object asks a Manager for the counter object corr to the folder.

Among approach1 & approach2 is better and why?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the second approach. Consider the scenario where you replicate more than one file at once. Your current design already supports this, just spawn another thread with its replication object.

If you go for the second route, you can still have the counter object remain in main thread, receiving signals from your worker threads to update the counters. The first approach, however, would not support this scenario.

Another scenario: Live view of the counts. If you have a gui or whatever that presents current data rate etc., it should not run in the worker thread. You would have to signal to the gui thread anyway. Having counting done at that place already comes handy.

To summarise: For me it seems that the second approach in your case is the more flexible one. It is also the one that introduces less changes to the current design (you can still throw away your objects and stay with the each replication has its own object paradigm).